# keySet and entrySet needing defined method?

Tags: java, treemap

It's rather ridiculous and I'm not sure WHY it's happening, but whenever I try to use `.keySet` or `.entrySet` I get the error in Eclipse to create a new method for it.

Answer (score 6):

The type `SparseMatrix` does not declare a method called `entrySet`. The type `TreeMap` does. You should be calling the method on a reference of that type. Possibly implement a getter that will retrieve the `matrix` field of an `SparseMatrix` object.

```
// inside the SparseMatrix class
public TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Double> getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}
```

Then call this method and chain the `entrySet()` invocation

```
public static boolean equals(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix b) {
    System.out.println("The entry set is:\n" + a.getMatrix().entrySet());
}
```

---

Remember that method invocation, at compile time, is resolved on the type of the variable. If that type doesn't declare, either directly or through inheritance, that method, a compilation error will occur.